# why line 14 is printed two times

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1,10)  #numbers 1 - 10
guess = None

while True:

    guess = input("pick a number from 1 to 10 \n")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < random_number:
        print("Too low")
    elif guess > 10:
        print("pick a number from 1 to 10")
    elif guess > random_number:
        print("It's high")
    else:
        print("You won")

        play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
        if play_again == "y":
            random_number = random.randint(1,10) #numbers 1 - 10
            guess = None
        else:
            print("Thank you for playing!")
            break
```

Comment: How would we know? you don't show us any input and output

Comment: Neither you tell us which line is line 14

Answer (score 0):

Because You print "pick a number from 1 to 10" and then follows input label at line 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you type a number greater than 10, it should print at least 3 times

```
guess = input("pick a number from 1 to 10 \n")

elif guess > 10:
        print("pick a number from 1 to 10")
```

Then the loop repeats

It's not clear why you've hard-coded 10 in the if-else. Rather you can try to continue the loop

```
while True:

    guess = input("pick a number from 1 to 10 \n")
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess > 10:
        continue
```

Comment: thank you I'm new to python i don't know anything about programming I'm a begginer

Comment: It's fine, but not an excuse for manually stepping through the code to understand its behavior and debug it